# Grails tagLib each loop

Tags: grails

I'm trying to get the index value on each loop around through a taglib. 
Example: This is rough dummy code.

```
        data.each() { item ->
            def index
out << "<option value='${item.name}'>item.name</option>"

        }
```

So data is just an array of objects. what i'm after is trying to get a index of each item in the each loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is easy to accomplish using `eachWithIndex`

```
data.eachWithIndex { item, idx ->
  out << "<option value='${item.name}'>${item.name}  - ${idx}</option>"
}
```